# Do I really need the sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate table?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping-methods, quote

We have a very simple logic for shipping methods and prices depending on the shipping country and the subtotal. We don't depend on any external API requests for the calculation. Do we really need to store the result inside the table?

My impression is, this table is only a performance optimization to avoid repeated expensive calculations or API requests to external shipping providers.

Has someone ever tried to turn this table off and found problems related to this? Which Problems were this?

**But most importantly:** do I really need this table, or can I workaround the logic to not use this table anymore?

Answer (score 3):

YES, I would recommend not removing or altering this core table. Quote = Cart and you could easily cause unforeseen issues by doing this.

For your shipping situation, I would highly recommend WebShopApps MatrixRate shipping method. This will do EXACTLY what you need and likely interacts with that table.

With the extension mentioned above, which is free, you can upload a CSV containing Country/Order Subtotal/Shipping Rate combinations. There is no need to do extensive modifications to achieve this when there is a proven extension. The last thing you would want are unintended side effects for a minor performance improvement.

I should also clarify that this table holds information about the quote. Let's say that your customer goes into the checkout steps, calculates shipping and proceeds to the next step but then leaves checkout but intends to return later. The previous selections would not persist and he would have to make selections all over again.

Comment: the selection is stored on the quote inside the shipping_method field, also the logic for the shipping methods is already there and very simple.